# Error Writing existing and populated Julia Dataframe to csv output

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe built out with various calculations performed on different rows. I'm trying to write the dataframe to a csv output, but keep getting the following error:
`` ArgumentError: `nothing` should not be printed; use `show`, `repr`, or custom output instead. ``

Here is the code:

```
filename = "Alldata.csv"
CSV.write(filename, bf)
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
 [2] print_to_string(::Nothing) at .\strings\io.jl:123
 [3] string(::Nothing) at .\strings\io.jl:156
 [4] writecell(::Array{UInt8,1}, ::Int32, ::Int32, ::IOStream, ::Nothing, ::CSV.Options{UInt8,UInt8,Nothing,Tuple{}}) at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\CSV\ztQqu\src\write.jl:281
 [5] macro expansion at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\CSV\ztQqu\src\write.jl:182 [inlined]
 [6] eachcolumn at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\Tables\FXXeK\src\utils.jl:49 [inlined]
 [7] writerow(::Array{UInt8,1}, ::Base.RefValue{Int32}, ::Int32, ::IOStream, ::Tables.Schema{(:bid, :building_name, :constr_year, :floor_area, :primary_type, :primary_
 [8] (::getfield(CSV, Symbol("##60#61")){getfield(CSV, Symbol("##53#54")){Bool,Tables.Schema{(:bid, :building_name, :constr_year, :floor_area, :primary_type, :primary_occupancy, :n_above, :period, :peak_pop, :eco_pop, :demo_cost, :renew_cost, :replacement_cost......
[9] #open#310(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::getfield(CSV, Symbol("##60#61")){getfie.....
 [10] open at .\iostream.jl:367 [inlined]
 [11] with(::getfield(CSV, Symbol("##53#54")){Bool,Tables.Schema{(:bid, :building_name, :constr_year, :floor_area, :primary_type, :primary_occupancy, :n_above, :period, :peak_pop, :eco_pop, :demo_cost, :renew_cost, :replacement_cost, :retro_cost, :retro_cost_notes, :perc_1, :perc_2, :perc_3, :perc_4, :perc_5, :perc_6, :perc_7, :perc_8, :perc_9, :perc_10, :perc_11, :n_col, :IM_43, :IM_200, :IM_475, :IM_2475, :PC_43, :PC_200, :PC_475, :PC_2475, :renew_cost3, :temp_cost, :tier3, :fr_HAZ, :cole_HAZ, :IM_975, :collapse_ext, :pcim_975, :theta3, :beta3, :theta4, :beta4, :tier4, :aaf4, :aafr, :pf4_50, :pfr_50, :annual_collapse, :pocc, :pf_col, :ri....
 [12] #write#52(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Array{String,1}, ::Function, ::Tables.Schema{(:bid, :building_name, :constr_year, :floor_area, :primary_type, :primary_occupancy, :n_above, :period, :peak_pop, :eco_pop, :demo_cost, :renew_cost, :replacement_cost, :retro_cost, :retro_cost_notes....
[13] write(::Tables.Schema{(:bid, :building_name, :constr_year, :floor_area, :primary_type, :primary_occupancy, :n_above, :period, :peak_pop, :eco_pop, :demo_cost, :renew_cost, :replacement_cost, :retro_cost, :retro_cost_notes, :perc_1, :perc_2, :perc_3, :perc_4, :perc_5, :perc....
[14] #write#51(::Char, ::Char, ::Nothing, ::Nothing, ::Char, ::Char, ::Char, ::Nothing, ::Bool, ::String, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(CSV.write), ::String, ::DataFrame) at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\CSV\ztQqu\src\write.jl:60
 [15] write(::String, ::DataFrame) at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\CSV\ztQqu\src\write.jl:53
 [16] top-level scope at In[177]:3
```

The dataframe exists and is populated since I can print it:

````
│ Row │ bid    │ building_name                       │ constr_year │ floor_area │ primary_type │ primary_occupancy │ n_above │ period   │ peak_pop │ eco_pop │ demo_cost │ renew_cost │ replacement_cost │ retro_cost │ retro_cost_notes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │ perc_1   │ perc_2   │ perc_3   │ perc_4   │ perc_5   │ perc_6   │ perc_7   │ perc_8   │ perc_9   │ perc_10  │ perc_11  │ n_col  │ IM_43 │ IM_200 │ IM_475 │ IM_2475 │ PC_43 │ PC_200  │ PC_475  │ PC_2475 │ renew_cost3 │ temp_cost │ tier3  │ fr_HAZ   │ cole_HAZ │ IM_975 │ collapse_ext │ pcim_975 │ theta3  │ beta3    │ theta4  │ beta4    │ tier4  │ aaf4      │ aafr       │ pf4_50   │ pfr_50   │ annual_collapse │ pocc     │ pf_col   │ risk_individual │ risk_individual_perc │
│     │ String │ String                              │ Int64⍰      │ Int64      │ String       │ String⍰           │ Int64⍰  │ Float64⍰ │ Float64  │ Float64 │ Missing   │ Float64⍰   │ Float64          │ Float64⍰   │ Union{Missing, String}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │ Int64 │ Int64  │ Int64  │ Int64   │ Int64 │ Float64 │ Float64 │ Float64 │ Float64⍰    │ Float64⍰  │ String │ Float64⍰ │ Float64⍰ │ Int64  │ Float64⍰     │ Float64⍰ │ Float64 │ Float64  │ Float64 │ Float64  │ Union… │ Float64   │ Float64    │ Float64  │ Float64  │ Float64         │ Float64  │ Float64  │ Float64         │ Float64              │
├─────┼────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────┼───────┼────────┼────────┼─────────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────┼───────────┼────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼───────────┼────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 22     │ LOWER MALL RESEARCH STATION         │ 1960        │ 75229      │ C2           │ Laboratory        │ 4       │ 0.37     │ 206.874  │ 68.9579 │ missing   │ 47.8929    │ 56.3446          │ missing    │ Lab wing 95% vulnerable - Office wing far less vulnerable at 5% collapse. New shear and frame ductility required.  Non structural risk high.                                                                                                           │ 0.85     │ 0.85     │ 0.9      │ 0.9      │ 0.8      │ 0.85     │ 0.9      │ 0.9      │ 0.9      │ 0.85     │ 0.9      │ 11     │ 43    │ 200    │ 475    │ 2475    │ 0     │ 0.0     │ 0.098   │ 0.42    │ 22.969      │ 47.8929   │ III    │ missing  │ missing  │ 975    │ 0.872727     │ 0.9      │ 2294.63 │ 0.951074 │ 572.462 │ 0.398816 │ V      │ 0.0970286 │ 0.00312973 │ 0.992183 │ 0.144857 │ 0.00179141      │ 0.333333 │ 0.785455 │ 0.000469024     │ 0.0469024            │
│ 2   │ 48     │ ANTHROPOLOGY AND SOCIOLOGY BUILDING │ 1975        │ 72384      │ C2           │ Office            │ 3       │ 0.2      │ 267.931  │ 60.2845 │ missing   │ 24.1623    │ 25.4339          │ 21.6189    │ Wings B and C highly vulnerable to collapse.  Lateral strength weakness very high, connections of roofs minimal. Mitigation would need to address adjacent ANSO buildings. Modelling includes assumtions about soil stability and foundation response. │ 0.95     │ 0.5      │ 0.5      │ 0.5      │ 0.5      │ 0.5      │ 0.7      │ 0.7      │ 0.5      │ 0.5      │ 0.5      │ 11     │ 43    │ 200    │ 475    │ 2475    │ 0     │ 0.0     │ 0.016   │ 0.582   │ 16.414      │ 24.1623   │ IV     │ missing  │ missing  │ 975    │ 0.577273     │ 0.9      │ 2111.45 │ 0.657641 │ 572.462 │ 0.398816 │ V      │ 0.0561079 │ 0.00273608 │ 0.939517 │ 0.127859 │ 0.00179141      │ 0.225    │ 0.519545 │ 0.000209412     │ 0.0209412            │
│ 3   │ 148    │ CHEMISTRY B BLOCK, SOUTH WING       │ 1959        │ 73590      │ C1           │ Laboratory        │ 3       │ 0.51     │ 180.63   │ 60.21   │ missing   │ 41.1035    │ 48.357           │ missing    │ missing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                │ 0.05     │ 0.05     │ 0.2      │ 0.1      │ 0.1      │ 0.0      │ 0.3      │ 0.3      │ 0.3      │ 0.8      │ 0.3      │ 10     │ 43    │ 200    │ 475    │ 2475    │ 0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.517   │ 26.943      │ 48.357    │ IV     │ missing  │ missing  │ 975    │ 0.25         │ 0.76     │ 2452.13 │ 0.217791 │ 753.719 │ 0.425775 │ V      │ 0.018312  │ 0.0027327  │ 0.599724 │ 0.127711 │ 0.00135172      │ 0.333333 │ 0.225    │ 0.000101379     │ 0.0101379 ```
````

Comment: Try this  bf.to_csv('Alldata.csv')

Comment: bf.to_csv throws a different error
```ArgumentError: column name :to_csv not found in the data frame

Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::DataFrame, ::typeof(!), ::Symbol) at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\DataFrames\uPgZV\src\other\index.jl:250
 [2] getproperty(::DataFrame, ::Symbol) at C:\Users\haley.sims\.julia\packages\DataFrames\uPgZV\src\abstractdataframe\abstractdataframe.jl:295
 [3] top-level scope at In[183]:5```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably on Julia 1.0. Try switching to Julia 1.3.1 (current release) and the problem should disappear.

If you have to stick to Julia 1.0 the problem is that `nothing` value is not allowed to be printed in this version (it is allowed now in Julia 1.3.1 so that is why switching solves your problem). In order to solve it the simplest thing is to replace `nothing` with `missing` (as probably if you have `nothing` in your data then `missing` is not used in it so it should be safe to use it as a replacement).

The code that will work in this case is:

```
filename = "Alldata.csv"
CSV.write(filename, something.(bf, missing))
```

After this operation in the saved file each occurrence of `nothing` in your original data frame will be stored as an empty field in a specific row (and when you read back the file using `CSV.read` it will take a `missing` value in the resulting data frame).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I did realize that the nothing value can't be written. Using something() solves this but an update is probably warranted. Thank you!

Comment: In general for "typical data" you probably should consider using `missing` instead of `nothing` anyway (here is a nice blog post to read why https://julialang.org/blog/2018/06/missing).